# Laravel save new record returns nothing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to save new record, all i get is a white page

even dump and dd for `$applicant ->save()` returns nothing.

```
  public function store(Request $request) {

    try {
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        $applicant = new Applicant();
        $applicant->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
        $applicant->middle_name = $request->get('middle_name');
        $applicant->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
        dump($applicant);
        $applicant->save();


      dd('Saved');
     } catch (Exception $e) {
         Log::error("Error during orders creation:" .$e>getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
```

I expected the record should be saved

Comment: Remove space in `$applicant ->save();`

Comment: sorry it was wrong just on copy. Not the real problem

Comment: did you check the database? please add dd($request->all(), $applicant) after the save and look what you got.

Comment: @AliÖzen I got the right data but any code after the save line not executed

Comment: If die dump is not executing after the save() line and you are getting blank page, you are probably executing another code and returning null from them. Like trait, observer, event, provider etc.

Comment: No it dump before save

Comment: did you dd($request->all()); ? requests are ok right? Then in the table is just first_name required right? If these are ok too. clear the route cache and dd($applicant) after the save again. You are skipping a step.

Comment: are you sure that you are not missing any values that are necessary for your table? @SaraShokry

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar Yes
on update records updated successfully

Comment: @AliÖzen I tried dd($request->all()) and the request is ok

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
    public function store(Request $request){
       $applicant = new Applicant;
       $applicant->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
       $applicant->save();
    }
```

and don't forget to include use App\Applicant model in your Controller class; If it does not solve your problem. please double check your form action post in view section.

Comment: very strange, it is supposed to work. what dd() function prints?

Comment: dd() prints nothing empty

Comment: do you allow data fillable data on model?

Comment: validation also prevent data to be submitted to db, will you post all your complete code?otherwise hard to debug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196746/discussion-between-sara-shokry-and-afikri).

Answer (score 0):

I think `save` function will not return anything.

for data you must use `create` method.

Comment: But I use it all the time and it works 
I'm using laravel 5.3

Comment: then it must have issue with data compact to view.

Answer (score 0):

Used return after save.

$applicant->save();

return response()->json(['success' => 'Data Added successfully.']);

Answer (score 0):

Use create in stead, write less code if you can us always better.
Try this:
Application::create($request->all());
Or change it the way you need by assigning every array key to its value